# Secure Cookies in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, web-config

I am still a little new to ASP.Net and am beginning to work with cookies. I have a somewhat understanding of them and was wondering something about them.

This is in regards to securing cookies. I have httpOnlyCookies set to true as seen below.

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
```

I noticed there was a Cookie.Secure property which I enabled as true. I did research on these two but am having trouble understanding the differences between the two. Can someone provide some direction on this? What would happen if I kept both set to true? What else can I do to secure cookies other than using SSL?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`httpOnlyCookies=true` is a site wide web config setting that prevents client side scripts from accessing the cookies. The cookie is still transmitted regardless of how secure the channel is i.e. via both `http` and `https`.

`Cookie.Secure` tells the browser to only send the cookie if the channel is secure. i.e. `https only`.

So the former setting describes what can access the cookie. The latter configures its transmission security requirements.

Comment: Cookie.HttpOnly - Gets or sets a value that specifies whether a cookie is accessible by client-side script.